Dumb question / thought - bonds and taxes
This is probably a very dumb question and can extend to non-bond securities but bonds were the simplest example of this:
For simplicity's sake just assume rates are zero and a there is a 10% coupon 5 year risk free bond.
Then the value today is 150 = 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + (10+100). So this is the value I can buy it at on the market.
However if I think about it from a corporate finance/NPV perspective as if these were the cash flows from some investment, if my tax rate is 30% then the NPV of the bond once I hold it is 135 = 7 + 7 + 7 + 7 + (7 + 100).
So when considering the cash outlay the NPV is 135 (from the cash flows) - 150 (from initial investment) = -15. In other words I'd be investing 150 to only receive 135 in net cash flows on a net present value basis, so the net present value of this transaction to me is -15. Why would I do this?
I suspect I am missing something very fundamental here in terms of mixing up an NPV style analysis with market valuations.
An extension of this - if I held a portfolio where the NPV was 135 and the market price quoted was 150, should I remove the taxes from the NPV calculation as the market price does not incorporate taxes?

Follow up thought - I suppose the initial cash outflow may reduce taxes in the first year?

135 from investing after taxes is still better than 100 from not investing and no taxes right? That's the decision you have to make. Though there is no doubt personal taxes detract substantially from the returns that investments promise, so that many of the returns bandied about in newspapers etc. are not really attainable.

Yes I suppose however the upfront amount required to receive this 135 is 150, as this would be the market price?

Bond cashflows are discounted. The market price of the bond is not the simple addition of all its future cashflows without discounting: making the basis of this question moot.

No need to be rude mate if you read the fine-print you'd see I said if rates were zero lol

The business paid 150 for a bond worth 150, so its net PnL is zero and so it should pay zero tax. At least, this would be the case under any reasonable accounting methodology! What the bond actually "does" in the future is less relevant.
